# Optimizing syncing of large dataset between 2 servers with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssdt

I have two DBs on different servers, Server A and Server B. Both are SQL Servers. I need to keep second DB in sync with the first one. DB schema and tables are identical, but Server A periodically creates new records that are missing on Server B. I decided to use SQL Server Integration Services, which is included in SSDT tools.

The simplest way to sync Server B with Server A is by creating SSIS project in Visual Studio that will generate `Package.dtsx`.

**Here is what the package does currently**

- create OLE DB source referencing Server A
- create OLE DB destination referencing Server B
- pick specific table that needs to be synced
- create column mapping for this table between Server A and Server B
- in SSMS, add SQL Server Job that will run `Package.dtsx` every 15 minutes

This package seems to download all the records from Server A and tries to insert them on Server B.

**The issues**

- Some records may already exist on Server B. Is there a way to **insert only records that are missing on Server B**, to prevent a bunch of errors in the log about duplicated primary keys?
- Server A may have a lot of records. Is there a way to **get the difference between servers BEFORE synchronization starts**, maybe there is some action that can compare records by IDs and download only the difference between servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a "[lookup](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-lookup-transformation-in-ssis/)" operator in your SSIS pacakage.
this package will "check" for some columns (your PK for example) and you will then be able to take action on only the rows that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your idea of downloading the keys, you could setup an initial dataflow of the PKs from ServerB to ServerA into either a permanent staging table or a temp table. Temp table usage in SSIS takes a bit of effort in that you'll want to enable Retain Same Connection on the connection object for ServerA where you'll hold the temp table, initially develop with a global temp table (with ##) so that it's visible during your development work and use Bypass Validation/Delay Validation so that SSIS doesn't throw an error when then temp table isn't visible (the temp table BTW should be created with an Execute SQL task prior to the initial data flow). Once downloaded you can compare keys locally on ServerA and only send the new ones to ServerB.